# How to create a recurrent variable with TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, recurrence

This sounds super easy but I cannot find any info on the internet. I am probably lacking some fundamental understanding.

I would like to do something simple: a recurrent variable. Say:

```
Z(t) = W * Z(t-1)
```

with some fixed (but trainable) `W`.

I tried things like:

```
initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer(0., 1.)
with tf.variable_scope('recurrent', initializer=initializer):
    Z = tf.get_variable('Z', shape=[...])
Z = tf.matmul(W, Z)
```

But of course, within a session, if I do `Z.eval()`, it gives a coherent value of `Z`, but `Z` itself is not updated.

Hence my question: how do you create a recurrent variable that gets updated when running the graph with TensorFlow?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write a statement like

```
Z = tf.matmul(W, Z)
```

you are updating the *python* variable `Z` and not the TensorFlow's internal storage associated with the TensorFlow variable `Z`. Please have a look at the [section](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/state_ops.html) on stateful operations in TensorFlow to get an idea of how TensorFlow manages state. To answer your specific question, you have to use the `tf.assign` operation to update TensorFlow's `Z` variable as follows :

```
Z = tf.assign(Z, tf.matmul(W, Z))
```

Comment: Hi keveman, thank you for your help. I tried tf.assign indeed but did not manage to get it working.
I just figured out that I was doing `tf.assign(Z, tf.matmul(W, Z)` instead of `Z = tf.assign(Z, tf.matmul(W, Z))`.......

Anyways, now it works as intended. Thank you very very much!!

Comment: Yes, `tf.assign` returns the value of TensorFlow variable *after* the assignment. Edited the answer to reflect that.